# Why does code break in jsfiddle

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've put together code in https://codepen.io/fjenpen/pen/pROPov but when I view it in https://jsfiddle.net/z05d3ufq/ #flexiselDemo3 breaks?

```
$('#flexiselDemo3 a').click(function(e) {
var target = $(this).attr("href");
$(".main .content").not(target).hide();
$(target).show();
return (false);
});

$(".main .content").hide();

var initialTarget = "#Section1";

if (location.hash.length > 0) {
initialTarget = location.hash;
}
$(initialTarget).show();
```

Comment: look in the browser console. for starters, you aren't including jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explicitly include jQuery within the JSFiddle console to ensure that it is used properly :

[image]

These browser-based "fiddle" tools can often each require their own specific way to reference external libraries, which could explain why it may work in one but not in the other.